# Adding a trailing slash to URLs in EE 3

Tags: url, ee3

I wonder if there is a way to add trailing slashes to the standard URLs generated by ExpressionEngine?

I'm not looking for some .htaccess rewrites but for a way to have slash appended in the first place.

Background is, that I'm migrating a site from EE1 (which had the default trailing slash, in case you remember) and there are thousands of entries with ten thousands of facebook-likes, google-plusses and whatnot that are to be preserved. So the URLs cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what template code you are using to craft the URLs. (I'm not sure about doing it at a DB level)

For example you could use:

```
{exp:channel:entries ... }
  ...
  <a href="{site_url}channel/{url_title}/" >Link</a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Or if `{url_title_path}` doesn't add a `/`, add one yourself:

```
{exp:channel:entries ... }
  ...    
  <a href="{url_title_path='channel'}/">Link</a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```